# regex in notepad++ -- searching my text string for \n\n is not working

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text string as below:

```
cmkcwlkmwfergneg
cmkcwlkmwfergneg
​
cmkcwlkmwfergneg
​
cmkcwlkmwfergneg
​
​
cmkcwlkmwfergneg
cmkcwlkmwfergneg
​
cmkcwlkmwfergneg
​
cmkcwlkmwfergneg
​
cmkcwlkmwfergneg
​
cmkcwlkmwfergneg
```

What I  want to do with the above text string is find any instances of the character string cmkcwlkmwfergneg which are followed by a blank line and then on that blank line, I want to insert the string abc.

So my attempt within notepad++ is:

Find what: `\n\n`

Replace with: `\nabc\n`

However when I try this in notepad++ it simply won't find any instances at all of `\n\n`.
For completeness I note that I have both the Match case and Wrap around ticboxes ticked within the notepad++ Replace dialogue box.

By contrast as well, I note that I have had not issues with running this replacement/substitution within regex101. See below:

https://regex101.com/r/EEXXEQ/1

Therefore can someone please assist in understanding why notepad++ doesn't like the `\n\n` match I am attempting? And what is an alternate solution that I can use in this case?

Comment: Then use `\R`, `(\R)(\R)` => `$1abc$2`

Comment: Many thanks, Wiktor, that worked. 

Can you explain why notepad++ preferred \R\R in this case? and why didn't it like \n\n ?

Comment: `\n` only matces LF. `\R` matches LFs, CRs and CRLFs safely.